# Why am I getting 404 Forbidden with a JSON P api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

So I am doing some testing with the food2fork api.

I seem to be getting a  404 forbidden.
Have looked and cannot find anything that has worked.
http://food2fork.com/about/api
Code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchTerm = $("#input").val();
        showResults(searchTerm);
    });


    function showResults(searchTerm) {
         $.ajax({
            key: "xxxx",///api key
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: "http://food2fork.com/api/search",
            q: searchTerm,
            success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: I get this is the Chrome browser console
GET http://food2fork.com/api/search?callback=jQuery21404141964341979474_1445240276656&_=1445240276657

Comment: you need to register on the website and then get api keys and then use the api keys to get search result http://food2fork.com/about/api

Answer (score 0):

The `q` and `key` properties of the object you're passing to `$.ajax` are ignored because they're invalid. It should be part of the request data.

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: { q: searchTerm, key: 'yourKey' },
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://food2fork.com/api/search",
        success: function (data) { alert('success'); }
});
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Still does not work.
New to APIS but I have already tried that.

Comment: It doesn't work because of other problems (possibly authentication) but you should keep in mind that this is the way to pass data as part of the request. Your current `{ q: .., key: ...}` is completely ignored.

Comment: Its not authentication.
I have tested the string with api key in browser and it shows the data.
Seems something is up.

Comment: I ca see the data in console but now im getting
search?callback=jQuery21402834362396970391_1445241859842&q=pizza&key=033660c66b597c1aa1646f81022fcf…:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :